# How to reset page number in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have following XSLT structure:

```
<fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="simpleA4" >                    
      <fo:region-body/>
      <fo:region-after extent="0.4cm"/>          
    </fo:simple-page-master>             
</fo:layout-master-set>

 <fo:page-sequence master-reference="simpleA4" >

    <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after">
      <fo:block font-size="5pt">
        Page <fo:page-number  />
      </fo:block>
    </fo:static-content>

    <fo:flow  flow-name="xsl-region-body">   
        <fo:block font-size="8pt">
            <!-Loop goes here->
        </fo:block>
    </fo:flow>

</fo:page-sequence>
```

Where I need to restart `<fo:page-number  />` again from 1 with respect to looping inside the body. Is it possible to reset page numbering or any alternative ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's possible, try this

```
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="simpleA4" initial-page-number="1" force-page-count="no-force">
```

and place the `fo:page-sequence` in you loop.

Comment: Thats it. I replaced the inner loop from inside the page sequence to outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you can reset fo:page-number thru xslt directly since page number is assigned by FOP. Its difficult to find out page number when page has dynamic content with unknown lines in a page. Did you try `<fo:page-number-citation/>` for this.

I suggest you that If you are sure each line has fixed lines, you can generate line numbers manually instead of using `<fo:page-number/>`. Remove `fo:static-content` node for generating page number and manually calculate page number and add it at end of the each page.

Let us assume your page has 80 lines, in body

```
for each 1 to totalRows
  add page header
  when rowCount%80=0
    add pageNumber
```

Comment: I have done something similar to this, assuming 35 fixed rows. The problem is that if any row cell get wrapped with a huge content then fixed count will be wrong. Anyway it will be good if XSLT has a feature to reset page number.

Comment: couldnt access stylusstudio there could get better result. see this thread http://www.oxygenxml.com/archives/xsl-list/200605/msg00425.html msg00436.html may get some idea.